# Oracle Order By Sorting: Column Values with character First Followed by number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have column values as

AVG,ABC, AFG, 3/M, 150,RFG,567, 5HJ

Requirement is to sort as below:

ABC,AFG,AVG,RFG,3/M,5HJ,150,567

Any help?

Comment: Does Oracle support collations with numeric sorting?

Comment: I must have not understood your requirements, because I don't see how any of the posted answers so far will return the rows sorted the way you asked.

Comment: Why 3/M goes before 150?  Shouldn't it order by the first character? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Any character in column value should get before a complete numeric string. I know its a very very odd sorting scenario. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort letters before numbers, then you can test each character.  Here is one method:

```
order by (case when substr(col, 1, 1) between 'A' and 'Z' then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when substr(col, 2, 1) between 'A' and 'Z' then 1 else 2 end),
         (case when substr(col, 3, 1) between 'A' and 'Z' then 1 else 2 end),
         col
```

Comment: @ryachza the query of yours returns the following ABC
AFG
AVG
RFG
150
3/M
5HJ
567 whereas my end output is a lil bit different.

Comment: @RohanK Yeah sorry I misread and thought you just wanted lexicographic but numbers second. Though this one still appears to transpose `3/M` and `5HJ`. Using something like: `(case when substr(col, 1, 1) between 'A' and 'Z' then 2 when substr(col, 1, 1) between '0' and '9' then 3 else 1 end)` appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't produce the requested output, but for lexicographic with numbers second `TRANSLATE` is a simple solution:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm

```
select value
from (
  select 'AVG' as value from dual
  union all
  select 'ABC' as value from dual
  union all
  select 'AFG' as value from dual
  union all
  select '3/M' as value from dual
  union all
  select '150' as value from dual
  union all
  select 'RFG' as value from dual
  union all
  select '567' as value from dual
  union all
  select '5HJ' as value from dual
)
order by translate(upper(value), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
;
```

This shifts all the letters down and numbers to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately within the sort order numbers are before chars.
I could suggest you the put an additional calculated column where you are adding 'ZZZ' in front of the values if they start with a number then you will sort by that virtual column

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't a large number of unique values, build a table that has the value and it's artificial sort order, then order by the sort key.  Something like:

```
create table sort_map
( value     varchar2(35),
  sort_order  number(4)
);

insert into sort_map (value, sort_order) values ('ABC',10);
insert into sort_map (value, sort_order) values ('AFG', 20);
....
insert into sort_map (value, sort_order) values ('150', 70);
insert into sort_map (value, sort_order) values ('567', 80);


--example query
select t.my_col, s.sort_order
from my_table t
join sort_map s
on (t.my_col = s.value)
order by s.sort_order;
```

Comment: can't go that way.... somehow do it by order by only at end of query not by a temp sort table way. anyways thanks for looking in to it...

Comment: Update your question with the additional requirements, as that wasn't specified.

Answer (score 0):

A) If you only want to change the order of full numberic secuences just create your isNumeric function:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE     isNumeric(field) ORDER BY FIELD
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT isNumeric(field) ORDER BY FIELD
```

B) If you want to change the order of characters.

Create a funtion that adds a number before every character with a modifier.

- Number -> 0
- Other  -> 2
- Letter -> 4

For example:

- shortHelper("2FT/") => "024F4T2/"
- shortHelper("AZ")   => "4A4Z"
- shortHelper("Z1")   => "4Z01"

Then use "ORDER BY shortHelper(Field)

Comment: Right now in a crunch situation. I will try the approach and let you know. Thanks Anyways!